# Show that number is divided by $137$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that if we are given a $4$-digit number and "double" it, the $8$-digit number that we become is divided by $137$.

How can we show this? Could you give me a hint?

We have to find what the number that we get is equal to modulo $137$ . But how can we get such an info?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "double" it?

Comment: If we have for example $1234$, then we get $12341234$.

Comment: I think it's asking whether $10001$ is a multiple of $137$. @Neal

Comment: $12341234 = 1234 \times 10001$. So the "double" of any 4-digit number is divisible by $10001$. How does this help you show that it is also divisible by $137$ ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well yes, but I think figuring out that's what it's asking is an important part of the exercise :)

Comment: Evinda, I want to share my "secret" way of solving problems like this. Try test cases to see how the land lies! If this is to hold for all 4-digit $a$s, then it will hold when $a=0001$, right? What does tell us? In that case the 8-digit number is just $10001$. So you need to check that first, ok? Moving on. With $a=0002$ we need to check $20002$. Wait, that's $10001+10001$. This might already suggest at least two ways of attacking the general case.

Comment: For the record, I'm not downvoting in this thread. The question could be improved, but... let's just say that I'm in possession of pieces of information unavailable to most non-mods. And, it wouldn't feel right for me to downvote here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My last 'deleted by downvoting' question was similar (it was not about 'doubling', but finding first seven digit number divisible by $137$). Please give your mod based approach, as would help me find better answer. I mean except by mod-based approach, need to remember that $10001 = 137.73$. Also, your mod-based approach would be generically applicable, not just one prime divisor.

Comment: @jiten In the comment above "mod" refers to "a site moderator". That comment was written shortly after I resigned from the moderator position. At the time I still remembered a few secret details about this post. Now it's under a layer of rust, but I still remember something. Anyway, I'm not going to post an answer here. That comment was about site politics - not math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any number: ( $n,m,s,t \in \{0,1,...,9\}, n\neq 0$ )

We form 4-digit number : W = $1000n+100m+10s+t $

Now, we "double" it, getting:

$1000\cdot10000n + 100\cdot10000m + 10\cdot10000s + 10000t + 1000n+100m+10s+t$

We can take $(1000n+100m+10s+t)(10000 + 1) $ = $10001\cdot W$

The question is, whether $10001$ is divisible by $137$.

It clearly is, because $10001 = 137\cdot73$

So

$137 \  | \ 10001\cdot W$

Answer (score 3):

**Starting out**: We need to precisely define our question. This means two things:

- Formulate what "doubling" means in terms of arithmetic operations
- Figure out precisely what we need to compute about the doubled number.

**Process**: We would like to show that for any four-digit integer $c$, the following is true:
$$ \operatorname{Double}(c) \equiv 0\ \operatorname{mod} 137 $$
So we need to figure out what "$\operatorname{Double}$" means. Let's use the example of $1234$. The double of $1234$ is $12341234$. Taking it apart:
$$ 12341234 = 12340000 + 1234 = 1234(10001). $$
So for a four-digit integer $c$, the double of $c$ is $10001c$.

**Putting it all together**: I'll let you take it from here!